# Subtract adjacent list elements

Tags: scala

My scala list contains following elements :

```
val A = List(12,1,34,34,45,56,7)
```

now I want to subtract list as below :

```
  List((12-1),(1-34),(34-34),(34-45),(45-56),(56-7))
```

so final result will be :

```
val result = List(11,-33,0,-11,-11,49)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to throw one more option into the mix:

```
(A zip A.drop(1)).map({ case (a, b) => a - b })
```

This gives you a little bit more type safety than `sliding` because `Tuple2` codifies the fact that the intermediate collection's elements are pairs.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need `sliding` (groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them):

```
A.sliding(2,1).toList.map(x => x(0) - x(1))
```

Comment: `1` is the default step, so `.sliding(2)` suffices.

Comment: You have a problem with singleton lists. You need either to add a `.filter(_.size > 1)` before the `map`, or replace the `map` by `.collect{case List(x,y) => x - y}`.

Comment: `A.sliding(2).map(_.reduce(_-_)).toList`

Comment: @HelderPereira true, also for empty lists (where all other answers also fail) :) In any case, I find Chris Martin answer the most correct one (assuming empty list is a special case which should be handled separately).

Comment: @jarandaf Definitively, empty list is a special, as the general rule seems to be `final_size = initial_size - 1`, it raises the question what to do with empty lists. In most cases, returning empty list will be OK (that's what your solution does), or maybe changing the return type to `Option[List[Int]]` and return `None` would make more sense, or if getting an empty list here is the diagnosis of a bigger problem that happened before, maybe we should throw an `Exception` instead of letting it silently returning an empty list. But that depends on specification and it was not specified by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

And let's don't forget `zipped`:

```
val A = List(12,1,34,34,45,56,7)
(A,A.drop(1)).zipped.map(_-_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
val list = List(12, 1, 34, 45)
list.sliding(2).map {
 case a :: b :: Nil => a - b
}.toList
```

It should return what you need.

Comment: You could use `collect` instead of `map` to avoid exception on `List(12)`.

Comment: Wow, you're correct. I'd expected `List(12).sliding(2)` to return an empty iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not impressed by the performance of the zip/map solutions.  This *could* be done with a simple iterator, overriding the `next()` method.  But I prefer streams

```
def subNeighbours(xs: List[Int]): Stream[Int] = xs match {
  case x :: y :: rest => (x - y) #:: subNeighbours(y :: rest)
  case _ => Stream.Empty
}

(subNeighbours(A)).toList
```

Inputs and outputs:

- `List(12, 1, 34, 34, 45, 56, 7)` => `List(11, -33, 0, -11, -11, 49)`
- `List(1, 3, 2, 9, 0, 5)` => `List(-2, 1, -7, 9, -5)`
- `List(1)` => `List()`
- `List()` => `List()`

Stream solution only traverses the list once.

Comment: Actually, this solution is slower than the `zip`/`zipped` solutions.

Answer (score -2):

Well, The thinking behind this would be:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.length-1; i++){
list[i]= list[i]-list[i+1];
}
```

Now just add in the small litter details like setting result to the final values and you are golden.